# CTI Integration recommendations

Tags: phone, voip

I am looking for feedback from anyone who has successfully installed CiviCRM with a CTI solution (Computer Telephony Integration) - what solution did you use, was the integration fairly seamless, would you recommend?

The solution must include:

- Address Book function
- Click to Dial (ideally)
- Caller Details Preview
- Contact match pop up
- Line called details
- Automatic call logging activity
- Integration with notes

Any advice or recommendations gratefully received

Comment: would be good to know the CMS you are using. we have built 'calling tools' in drupal using Views and Webforms, but have never gone that extra step with CTI